# How to remove duplicate rows in excel but keep the one with largest number

Tags: excel, duplicates

If I have two rows that have duplicate code and name as in this example,

how can I remove only the one that has the lowest qty (in this example: the first line)

I tried using the remove duplicates option but it is removing the second line

[image]

Is there some sort of formula I can set to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Sort by code then by descending quantity then remove duplicates.

Comment: @Warcupine I tried it now it did not work. It keeps deleting the one with largest number. I cannot remove them manually because there are about 10,000 rows

Comment: You messed up your sort if that didn't work, it will delete any duplicate after the first one.

Comment: Sorry, It worked, I sorted them in ascending order instead of descending.
Thank you so much.